# The third eye of lord shiva

Tags: shiva, spiritual-level, spirituality, chakras

I've known that the third eye is actually the place for 'agna' chakra in the body, and that the third eye is actually a metaphor for reaching that high level of conciousness where you start seeing things the way they are. And lord shiva, who is 'trilochana' clearly shows this by his form, and his actions of, for instance, destroying 'kama'(lust) with his third eye.
This would actually be a metaphoric action, which would mean, if you have attained highest knowledge, then you can destroy lust, which is persistent to human nature.

**But my biggest confusion** is, if the third eye is the symbol of knowledge and highest conciousness, why does the third eye of lord shiva open up with rage? Knowledge as any one would say would be obtained with time, patience and effort, in the contrary, why would our energy reach the 'agna' with rage?

EDIT: **ARE THERE ANY VERSES TO SUPPORT YOUR REMARKS**?

Comment: "rage" doesn't mean the rage you meant, it means the energy and the knowledge at this point is highest among all energy which is uncontrollable for any sAdhakA. The metaphoric meaning is if one person reaches at this point, it has to be controlled or else it may cause side effects. The name "Ajna" chakra itself means "command". So one has to send a command to control, it could be your Guru mostly who will do that. When the time comes, you should be able to control by yourself.

Comment: Third eye is the seat of ego, a meditator gets ego "That he is superior to others", but the truth is meditation itself is delusion and is for beginners. In non-duality, there is no meditation nor meditator, only silence is present. That story is taught to people to make them understand, that anger cant destroy lust nor Kamdeva, only wisdom or Bhakti can. https://www.sriramanamaharshi.org/teachings/%D7%97%D7%A1%D7%93/

Comment: @ManuKumar ,any scripts or verses that depict this?

Answer (score 1):

Rightfully and technically, it is the rage property that comes out through the third eye on command from Paramatman. Ajna is also the seat of  YOUR consciousness -Jivatma. It is where you realize  Paramatma through Self-realization. Almost, all the realized saints experience bliss during self-realization not rage. At Ajna, your Guru is none other than ParaBrahman. Now, the rage comes out of the third-eye in the form of the energy is to set right something that goes against the will of Parabrahman. You move above lust clutches is the right way to understand it.

Comment: could you please look at my edit?

Comment: I cannot give you verses. In fact there is just knowledge there are no written verses.why is rage required? I can give a hint. Google for answers : Main title